# Connecting a GUI to the User-Created function in postgresql-8.4.15

Tags: java, database, user-interface, jdbc

I have been given a task to create profiles for the applications. The Database that we use is Postgresql. I've defined some function that will give me those profile and I've added them to the Postgresql source code. Now I don't know how to call those functions with a GUI. I mean how connect my Graphical user interface to those functions that I've created. For example I have a button in my GUI that is "Start creating profiles" and it's supposed to call those functions in postgresql source code code and so on...

Any ideas of how to call those function from my GUI?

I deeply appreciate your kind help in advance!

Based on the replies, in order to use the JDBC to connect my GUI to postgreSQL, I wrote this code but I have a problem with "URL"

I know these commands in Java to connect to database(PostgreSQL):

```
Connection con = null;
Statement s = null;

String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb";
String user = "user";
String password = null;

try {
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName());
           lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
           out.println(ex.getMessage());
} 

String query = " select * from my_function()";
try {
       s =con.createStatement();
       r = s.executeQuery(query);
}catch (Exception e){
}finally {
 try {
 if (con != null) 
con.close();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(HomeServlet.class.getName());
              lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

But I'm not sure about what I have to insert in "URL"
Would you please help me with that!

Comment: What programming language do you use to create your GUI?

Comment: java but if I have to change it I will

Comment: You need JDBC and then run e.g. `select * from my_function()` to retrieve the results. Start with the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I just edited my question based your reply. I appreciate if you take a look at my modified question and help me with that

Comment: I've created a function in "postgres.c" and I need to call it using GUI I've created by netbeans. In the code I wrote above in order to connect to postgreSQL and calling that function, I have to write the URL of the database I want to connect to but since the function that I've defined is inside "postgres.c", I don't know what should I write as URL. for exapmle ""String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb";"" But I have no idea how to call my function from 'postgres.c". What URL should I write as the database URL ?